# Compiling Ruby C++ Extension

Tags: c++, ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to compile a c++ extension for Ruby, and the compilation does not return an error, but it does not seem to be compiling correctly. What am I doing wrong?

I have the main cpp script **foo.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ruby.h>
extern "C"

VALUE cFoo;
void Init_foo(){cFoo = rb_define_class("Foo", rb_cObject);}
```

and **extconf.rb**:

```
require "mkmf"
$libs += " -lstdc++ "
create_makefile("foo")
```

and within the directory of these files, I did

```
$ ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
$ make
compiling foo.cpp
linking shared-object foo.so
$ ls
Makefile extconf.rb foo.cpp foo.o foo.so
```

Then, I have a Ruby script **test.rb**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "path_to_this_directory/foo"
```

and I run `test.rb`. It returns an error:

```
... in `require': .../foo.so: undefined symbol: cFoo - .../foo.so (LoadError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Environment**

- OS: Ubuntu Linux 11.10
- Ruby: 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring that `cFoo` exists:

```
extern "C"

VALUE cFoo;
```

but you never define it. Saying `extern "C" blahblah` just says that `blahblah` exists, that it is externally visible, and that it won't have its name mangled (i.e. "C" linkage) but an `extern` declaration doesn't actually define anything; `extern` says that something exists but it doesn't bring it into existence.

Your C++ should look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ruby.h>

extern "C" VALUE cFoo;
extern "C" void Init_foo();

VALUE cFoo;
void Init_foo(){cFoo = rb_define_class("Foo", rb_cObject);}
```

You need two `extern "C"` to tell the C++ compiler to leave the names alone and then separate definitions for the symbols. You could also say this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ruby.h>

extern "C" VALUE cFoo;

VALUE cFoo;
extern "C" void Init_foo(){cFoo = rb_define_class("Foo", rb_cObject);}
```

I'm not sure if the second version is standard C++ or a GCC extension.

I'm not much of a C++ person so I hope I haven't butchered the terminology too badly.